# Steam "trading confirmations" settings to remove 15 days hold

Tags: steam

I have been using Mobile steam app and got authenticated since January, after the new updates on system "March 9", I am getting trade holds for 15 days, but I knew I am already mobile authenticated since Jan. On march 10 or 11, I tried to remove and re-authenticated on steam app, guessing i need to ,because of the update. After weeks and up to now, I am still getting trade hold for 15 days.

I looked on forums and reddit about this.
I got this. "activate both options "Trade confirmations" and "Community market confirmations".
but I don't have this options on my privacy settings both on my Chrome browser, steam client and steam app. I can't find anything about this.

I confirm sell listings and trades on steam mobile app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is verify that indeed you have Steam Guard (Mobile Authenticator) enabled by clicking on your name then "Account Details" and scrolling to "Account Security".

It should look something like this:
[image]

This means that your Mobile Authenticator is correctly activated.

However **to prevent trade holds you need to have the Mobile Authenticator active for 7 days straight**. Since you mentioned removing your Mobile Authenticator on March the 10th or 11th then you should have your trade holds removed March the 17th or 18th.

Additionally keep in mind that it's relatively easy to remove your Mobile Authenticator on the App itself. I've actually accidentally removed it once by logging out of the App.

More information can be found [here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/494631967656381975/) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=495405494).

Comment: [Account security](http://i.imgur.com/hzmuqf4.png?1)

I am sure that I activated it on March 10 8am, I checked it on my email. by now (GMT +8:00) 7 days should have been passed.

I tried to change it to email confirmation once on feb, and waited 7 days. it did not help on my holds.

I think im going to wait for one more day and if its still wont work, I would get steam support.

Thanks for the tip on logging out. I never been logged out on steam app since i started using it.

Thanks.

Comment: @Patrich everything seems to be fine. It should be a matter of waiting a little longer. E-mail confirmations won't do anymore it has to be the Steam Mobile Authenticator. No problem, contact Steam support like you've said if the problem persists ;).

Comment: I don't have trade holds anymore, I guess my account was delayed, It took 8 days for me. I still not getting "Trade confirmations" and "Community market confirmations" settings though. But what really matters to me is the trade hold. Thanks Joao

Comment: @Patrich sometimes it takes a while longer for Steam to update this kind of information on their servers. Glad I could be of assistance :).

Comment: Does this mean I need to get a code once a day for seven days or just need to have had it active for 7 days?

Comment: @PremierBromanov No, you just need to have the application active ;). As long as your Account Security looks like the image I posted you're good to go, you just need to wait 7 days after that ;).

Comment: @JoãoNeves thanks, that helps. The wording could go either way

Comment: @PremierBromanov Anytime!

Comment: @JoãoNeves hi! 2018 here! how do you activate Mobile authenticator straight 7 days? should I be connected all the time in the internet and let the program(steam guard) run on the background of my phone for 7 days?

Comment: @Mr.J all you have to do is make sure your settings are like the image above. Then don't change those settings for 7 or more days ;). There's no need to run it on background ;).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. My problem was the confirmations on my mobile authenticator were being sent to my email address instead of my phone.  You can change that on your phone through the Mobile Guard settings, and set it to have confirmations sent to your phone.  After you do that, remove the listing of the item you want to sell and then put it back up.  You will then have a confirmation sent to your phone and you can create the listing there and there will not be anything put on hold.

This is how it worked for me, and I hope it does the same for you.